# How can I call an external API (only to push data) in a smart contract?

Tags: go-ethereum

I read that there are solutions like http://www.oraclize.it/ to bring external data into a smart contract.

Is there a simpler way if I only want to notify an external service (no need to bring in external data) when a method in a contract has been called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is for the contract method to emit an event.  Server code is listening for these events, and then notifies the external service.

Another way is to instrument a client.  For a Python example see:

https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Making-a-User-Service:-Tutorial

> One of pyethapp's most powerful distinguishing features is its ability
>   to easily create built-in user services: scripts written in python
>   that run alongside pyethapp, and run code on startup and every time
>   you receive a new block. This allows you to create "server daemons"
>   for applications that require periodic automated support, such as
>   RANDAO, data feeds, "decentralized dropbox" apps, alarm clocks,
>   decentralized cloud computing services, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to blockchain. The first option (server listening to logs) would only work if I had access to the miners that mine any state changes on the contract, correct? For the second option, when I receive a new block, what information will it contain with regards to changes in the smart contract? Just the new values of all variables of the contract?

Comment: Events are visible to everyone with a node. While the name "log" suggests something informal, they're perfect for a well-organized, cheap and possibly indexed/searchable storage that's accessible in the outside world. In my opinion it's usually best to write the contract so it emits events for all state changes such that the complete history of the contract could be conceivably reconstituted from the events. You would have events for things like thingAdded, thingUpdated, thingDeleted and include the variables needed to understand the message. Servers or clients listen and react.

Comment: @migu, the event logs are a sort of visible searchable output of transactions. You use this to identify if the transaction that has jus been mined has something to tell you for your contract. Then, realize that when a contract state is modified by a transaction that is mined into a block, the full contract state (all its data) are inside de block.

Comment: When you query the contract values (via constant functions or getters) by default you get the values of the contract in its latest version (ie the version of the state of the contract stored in the latest block or the one before, etc). If you need to get the contract state at a different point in time you can call the constant functions with a block number to tell the API to read at or before that block.

Comment: @GuenoledeCadoudal Thanks. So to get the change in states of a contract, I need compare the state in a block vs the state in an earlier block. The block itself doesn't hold any changes (delta values), only the latest values, correct? Thanks

Comment: @migu correct. Contrary to bitcoin ledger managing debit/credit in the blocks, ethereum manage the final state after each transaction. This is easier when you manage a virtual machine to change the states.